# Spring Security logout насройка

Tags: spring, авторизация, spring-security, logout

Не могу нормально настроить logout:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
```

НО

При переходе по ссылке логаута выдает 404

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary" th:href="@{/logout}">Sign out</a>
```

**(P.s. я так же пробовала не трогать логаут в принципе)**

Как вариант так же пробовала сделать попроще:

```
.logout()
.logoutSuccesUrl("/"); //на этом все
```

Но в любом виде он выдает 404. Что мне сделать чтобы он просто вышел?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете создать какой нибудь **Controller**, с маппингом на **"/logout":**(например)

```
    @GetMapping("/logout")
    public String logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication != null) {
            request.getSession().invalidate();
        }
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

Если останутся проблемы с "redirect:/", то опять же можете еще создать метод с маппингом "/", и там явно делать return (вашей страницы на удачный logout, либо на редирект на логин, и т.д.)

```
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String root() {
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
```